# Better way to test for null?

Tags: apex, soql

I've got an AggregrateResult that has several SUMs in it like this:

```
Select SUM(Optical__c) HWOpti,SUM(Tcal__c) TCal, SUM(POS__c) POSHWOpt
```

Each of those fields are of currency. So I want to then do some calculations.

So I do this for each SUM result first:

```
HWOpti_a = (double) results.get('HWOpti');
```

If the SUM result is null then the resulting conversion to double results in a null. Then the calculation fails and throws and error.

So I just did a bit of null checking for each SUM result like this:

```
    if(results.get('HWOpti') != null)
        HWOpti_a = (double) results.get('HWOpti');
     else
        HWOpti_a =0;
```

It works but it seems a bit messy. Is there a better way to check for the null or make sure that the SUM results in at least a zero even if all the values summed are null?

Comment: Unless your data is populated with zeros instead of nulls, that's going to happen when the aggregrate results are calculated. About the only other method is to use a try-catch block to capture the null pointer exception that would occur from trying to access the null value. You're doing what's necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A common strategy for this is to write a method called `elide`. It can be written for `Integer`, `Decimal`, `Long`, etc. as well.

```
public static Double elide(Double input)
{
    return (input == null) ? 0 : input;
}
```

It seems simple but this syntactic sugar really helps, especially if you are using values inline in your calculations.

```
Double c2 = elide(a2) + elide(b2)
```

**If you would like to see this feature included natively** in `Apex`, vote for [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cGGlAAM) by @sfdcfox.

Comment: That looks great.  Just what I was looking for.

Comment: @LeeFranke Also, vote on https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cGGlAAM and https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DjPQAA0. This would eliminate the need for such a function.